# MAC OSX Yosemite - matplotlib

Tags: python, macos, numpy, matplotlib, osx-yosemite

I would like to install matplotlib on a MAC OSX Yosemite 
I've tried these things:

```
sudo port install py25-matplotlib +cairo+gtk2
Password:
sudo: port: command not found
```

__

```
sudo pip install -U matplotlib
zsh: correct matplotlib to .matplotlib ? ([Y]es/[N]o/[E]dit/[A]bort)
```

__

```
pip install matplotlib
zsh: correct matplotlib to .matplotlib ? ([Y]es/[N]o/[E]dit/[A]bort)
```

does a file when I want to use matplotlib also need import `numpy as np`? 
Can I even download matplotlib on a MAC OSX?

What am I doing wrong? :(

Comment: Do you have [MacPorts](http://macports.org) installed? If not, that's why your `port` command is failing. Also, why were you trying to install the Python 2.5 version? If you have pip set up correctly, `sudo pip install -U matplotlib numpy` should install those packages and their dependencies.

Comment: I've got Pip well installed(as far as I know) , everything else does install with pip. But when I do sudo pip install matplotlib numpy it says: zsh: correct matplotlib to .matplotlib ? ([Y]es/[N]o/[E]dit/[A]bort)  (I don't have MacPorts installed)

Comment: Just pick No - you don't want to change the command. This is why I don't use zsh...

Comment: My recommendation is to use [homebrew](http://brew.sh/), and then use the python science recipe  laid out here: https://joernhees.de/blog/2014/02/25/scientific-python-on-mac-os-x-10-9-with-homebrew/. Finally, I would make sure to install virtualenv and virtualenv wrapper if that's the rout you plan to take.